# My "data default (getdate())", it doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, date, aspnetdb

I'm trying to insert in my SQL Server table the current date.

My table includes 3 files:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
     [Id]   INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
     [Date] DATE 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_Date] DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

When a new user wants to register in the system, he has only to insert his name.

In my table, the Id is generated automatically and the date too, but the date shows `01/01/0001` instead of the current day.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: You must be sending it a `new DateTime()`. Make your date variable nullable (`DateTime?`) and make sure its value is null.

Comment: If I put a Null in the DATE variable, when I click in "View Data" I get a NULL instead of the current date.

Comment: I don't know what "View Data" is or how it is implemented. I created your table in my sql server and issued this query and successfully got today's date. The problem is in your .net code which you have not shown. `insert into MyTable (name) values ('foobar');`

Comment: With "View Data" I was talking about the SQL Server Object Explorer inside my Visual Studio.

I checked my sql server and it works with the current date like you said, but I don't understand why that date doesn't shows in the SQL Server Object Explorer inside my Visual Studio, when I to register an user in my asp.net mvc web application.

Comment: Your default only ever gets used if you **do not** specify that column in your insert, e.g. if you have `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Name) VALUES(N'xxxxxx');` - if you specify the column and pass in a value (or even `NULL`), then your default **will NOT be used**.

Comment: The problem is in your C# code, not your SQL. Edit your question and show the C# code you use to insert.

Comment: The above 3 comments are your root problem and solution. (said slightly 3 different ways.)  Follow Crowcoder  Jorge  and marc_s advice.

Answer (score 0):

if you create a datetime variable in C# like

var `today_date = new DateTime();`

and do a  `Console.WriteLine(today_date);` u can see it print `0001-01-01`

So this  is default value of null..

Use `DBNull.Value` to insert a `SQL NULL` from `C#` and check the result

Answer (score 0):

[image]

(Your_Date_Column) Make it Null / Not Null and give default value GetDate() but still it will not work. You have to create a trigger like this,

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_Date] ON [dbo].[TableName] FOR INSERT AS BEGIN

```
Declare @Id int
set @Id = (select Id from inserted)

Update [dbo].[TableName]
Set Your_Date_Column = GetDate()
Where Id = @Id
```

END

Answer (score 0):

Functions and triggers are not required. Just set a column with type `Date` or `DateTime` to `NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Updated example code from the question:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
     [Id]   INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
     [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

     CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```